# How to find the metadata (byte offset & byte order) of a tiff file

Tags: image, offset, endianness

I am doing a meta analysis on some old image data that sits in tiff files. I am not sure how they were generated but I need the byte order and offset to read the file into another program. How can I read this? I can open the file in different programs but that does not provide the low level detail of the tiff format needed.

Anyone aware of a way of inspecting image files at this low level?

Comment: The byteorder is given by the first 2 bytes, either `MM` for Motorola or `II` for Intel. You haven't tagged with a specific language? See Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF

Comment: Try [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/), e.g., `python -c"from tifffile import TiffFile;import sys;t=TiffFile(sys.argv[1]);print(t.tiff.byteorder, t.pages[0].dataoffsets);t.close()" test.tif`

Comment: @cgohlke I think that comment would make a good answer. Don't hide your many talents under a bushel

Comment: @cgohlke This is great please make it an answer so I can give you credit. Quick question though what does byte order "<" mean

Comment: `<` means *"little endian"*. `>` means *"big endian"*.  See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html